# Find $P(X+Y>1)$ probability of density function

Tags: probability, statistics

Yet another PDF question.

I am given the following joint density function,

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{2}{5}\text{ when }0<y<1\text{ and } 0<x<5y$$

And have to calculate the probability that $X+Y>1$

I have drawn a figure which shows the area in question,

The red area is where the PDF equals $\frac{2}{5}$, and the area to the right of the line $y=1-x$, is where $X+Y>1$

[image: density function area]

So if I understand correctly, I have to double integrate the PDF to find the area to the left of the line. But im not having any luck getting the correct answer.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

<strike>According to my professor, the answer should be P(X+Y>1)=5/6</strike>

Did he make a mistake or is my figure wrong? :/

**EDIT2 (Follow-up problem):**

EDIT3:

Moved new problem to an entirely new question.

[Find $P(X<Y<1)$ probability of two-dimensional density function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466062/find-pxy1-probability-of-two-dimensional-density-function)

Comment: You drew $y = 1 - x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compute the area of the small triangle on the bottom left, and subtract it from the total area. Then multiply by the probability, 2/5.

Combining $y = 1 - x$ and $x = 5 y $ yields $ y = 1 - 5y$, $y = 1/6$, $x = 5/6$.
The area of the small triangle is thus ${1\over 2} \cdot w \cdot h = {1\over 2} \cdot 1 \cdot y = {1\over 12} $

The area of the large triangle is ${1\over 2} \cdot 5 \cdot 1 = 5/2$ (obviously, otherwise the probability wouldn't sum to 1).

Subtracting the two and multiplying with 2/5: $ (5/2 - 1/12) \cdot 2/5 = 29/30$.

Comment: Alright, so I was on the right track. The only problem is that the result should be 5/6 (unless my professor made a mistake, or my figure is wrong)

Comment: I think your figure and j13r's answer are both correct.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, awesome. Also, I would appreciate some help with my follow-up problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can take $\int_{5/6}^1 \int_{1-x}^{x/5} \frac{2}{5} dy dx +\int_{1}^5 \int_0^{x/5} \frac{2}{5} dy dx$ to get the answer.

As you indicate, you could also take $1-\int_0^{1/6}\int_{5y}^{1-y} \frac{2}{5} dx dy$.